# Glatt vs Beit Yosef Glatt

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, words, shulchan-aruch, yoreh-deah

I’m curious what the  difference in Halacha is between standard Glatt and “Beit Yosef” Glatt kosher? My understanding is the difference between Glatt and non-Glatt is the lungs, but what makes Beit Yosef Glatt unique compared to standard market Glatt?